# get month and year from javascript and show in multiple sections in a html page

Tags: javascript, html

I have the js code to get month and year and i need to show this output to 6 sections in one page. I have been searching in google and also I have looked in to SO but I couldnt find the exact answer anywhere, maybe someone can post the link please in case this question turns out to be duplicate. The js code below:

```
var mydate = new Date(),
    year = mydate.getFullYear();
var month = mydate.getMonth(),
    montharray = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
monthyear = (" " + montharray[month] + " " + year);
document.getElementById("my1").innerHTML = monthyear;
```

Since the ID cant be used more than once in a page, I thought why not just add 6 IDs like following:

```
document.getElementById("my2").innerHTML = monthyear;
document.getElementById("my3").innerHTML = monthyear;
document.getElementById("my4").innerHTML = monthyear;
document.getElementById("my5").innerHTML = monthyear;
document.getElementById("my6").innerHTML = monthyear;
```

Sorry I am not a coder so I just found a workaround but I am sure this is not the efficient way of showing the output. I was working with queryselectorall after looking at various examples in SO but I couldn't make that work at all. Please any guidance is appreciated ! Thank you.

Comment: IDs have to be unique, that's why classes were invented :) Also, you're writing code, so you're officially a coder!

Comment: To clarify, you're looking to reuse your monthyear functionality in 6 different places?

Comment: @Isolated Yes, like May 2020 needs to be shown in 6 different places in one page. Thank you.

Comment: @JeremyThille Thank you for the info on class. Learning from all the experts in SO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function monthDateFormatted() {
  const date = new Date();

  const years = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { year: 'numeric' }).format(date);
  const month = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', { month: 'long' }).format(date);

  return `${month} ${years}`;
}
```

I hope this helps, simply reuse the method monthDateFormatted where you set the innerHTML. (or anywhere else you need this function, inside a footer, perhaps)

You could shorten the method, combining the two formatted Dates, however for readability I thought I'd keep it simple.

You *could* always add an argument:

```js
function monthDateFormatted(aDate) {
  const date = aDate || new Date();
  // .. rest of function
}
```

Entirely up to you.

**Note: this API (Intl.DateTimeFormat) may not be supported in older versions of Internet Explorer**

Comment: Thank you. Could you please give me an example of html section as well ?

Comment: Here's a working JSFiddle you can view, keep in mind, I'm pretty lazy so I went for iteration, in reality you'd like need to update them in different parts but hopefully you'll get the idea. Hopefully this helps. https://jsfiddle.net/kqof2g4j/

Comment: Awesome !! This is exactly what I was looking for :) , just a question if I have to show it in 8 different places, that number 6 inside the function has to be replaced by 8 ?

Comment: Yes sir! Iteration is a simple process, what's in between the `for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {` will be repeated 6 times, essentially whilst i is *less than* 6, you can change 6 to 8, 10, 100, 1000 just be wary, the more times you repeat the process (the higher that number), you'll have to wait increasingly longer for the completion. I don't want to bog you down with technical details, but bare it in mind, if you ever get a chance in future have a look into Iteration, you may find it interesting. You gain the ability to reduce the amount of repeated code, at a cost of performance.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to do in pure JS, but with [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) it really becomes a no brainer :

```js
const thisMonth = moment().format("MMMM YYYY");

const divs = document.getElementsByClassName("date");

for( let div of divs) {
  div.innerHTML = thisMonth
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.3/moment.min.js"></script>

<div class="date"></div>
<div class="date"></div>
<div class="date"></div>
<div class="date"></div>
<div class="date"></div>
<div class="date"></div>
<div class="date"></div>
<div class="date"></div>
<div class="date"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you and its a great solution but one downside is that its affecting page loading time due to the moment js  :)

Comment: Is it possible to provide an example of getelementsbyclassname without using moment js please? thank you.

Comment: Sure, the other answer by @Isolated is what you need. Also, Moment is an extra script to load, but 1. from a CDN it's very fast (58 Kb), 2. The following times, it will be loaded from the browser's cache, and 3. it's totally, totally worth it if you manipulate dates in your app. Makes your life so much easier.